# android 4.1.2 text color in the html code not working

Tags: java, android, html, fonts

My apps configs are min sdk 2.1 and targeting android 4.x, I tried html in java and html in string.xml to make part of a word in TextView red,  in the emulator (androied 2.2)is working perfect, but on my galaxy mini Android 4.1.2 font color change doesn’t work !!
In java I used :

```
tv1.setText(Html.fromHtml("<BOLD>book<font color=\"RED\">s</FONT></BOLD>"));
```

and in xml I used :

```
<string name="tvCh2SubT1"><bold>Adding \"<font color="red">S</font>\" to make words plural</bold></string>
```

And this is a screen shot of my application setup:
[image]

thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

The `<font>` tag is only supported in older versions of `HTML`, is not valid in `HTML5`.

It might be because the Android 2.1 device defaults to parse the older versions of `HTML`, but the 4.1.2 is defaulted to `HTML5`.

If my guess is correct, the following code should work:

`tv1.setText(Html.fromHtml("<BOLD>book<span style="color:red">s</span></BOLD>"));`

rather than using `<font color=somecolor>`, use the `HTML5` with `CSS` version, `<span style="color:somecolor">` instead.

Comment: thank you kaho, it didn't work but i my old code after changing the quotes around color=\"red\" to single quote and removing the escape slashes  works fine:  tv1.setText(Html.fromHtml("<BOLD>book<font color='red'>s</fon></BOLD>"));       so just changing  color=\"red\"    to color='red'  solved the problem (notice we don't need to escape the single quote). thank you all again

Answer (score 1):

Do not use color's name use it's hex code.

use `"<font color=\"#FFFFFF\">"`

rather than

```
<font color=white>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your xml String:

```
<string name="tvCh2SubT1">"<b>Adding \"<font color='red'>S</font>\" to make words plural</b>"</string>
```

And then why not set the text to the TextView in your layout xml?
It is also capable of HTML.

Comment: unfortunately your code doesn't work, and I am using a TextView to display the string, as I said earlier, my code works in the emulator with android 4.x and 2.2 but it doesnwork on my mobile android 4.1.2 , i am sure it is something to do with the sdk version setup (screen shot above) ) but can't figure it out, what is the best combination to target compatibility with most android version? I thought my setup was making it compatible with 2.1 to 4.x but its not !

Answer (score 0):

my old code after changing the quotes around color=\"red\" to single quote and removing the escape slashes works fine:

```
tv1.setText(Html.fromHtml("<BOLD>book<font color='red'>s</font></BOLD>"));
```

so just changing color=\"red\" to color='red' solved the problem (notice we don't need to escape the single quote). thank you all again